# Access 2002 and VBA: Test for field in recordset

Tags: ms-access, vba

Consider:

```
Do Until rs.EOF = True
    Me.vcTBConcatName.SetFocus
    If IsNull(rs.Fields!contactname.Value) Then
        Me.vcTBConcatName.Text = "No value recorded"
    Else
        Me.vcTBConcatName = rs.Fields!contactname
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

The object of this code snippet is to: set the focus on a textbox (vcTBConcatName), check whether a value for `contactname` exists in a record set, populates the textbox with the value if it exists, or populates the textbox with `No value recorded` if not.

The code runs, and populates the textbox ONLY if there is a value for `contactname` in the recordset.  No alternative text is placed in the textbox in case there is no value returned for `contactname`.

Could someone point to what I am doing wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will work for you.  If you are just searching for a value, you don't have to loop through the recordset:

```
Me.vcTBConcatName.SetFocus

rs.FindFirst "[contactname] IS NOT NULL AND [contactname] <> ''"

If rs.NoMatch Then
    Me.vcTBConcatName = "No value recorded"
Else
    Me.vcTBConcatName = rs.Fields!contactname
End If
```

The code looks for the first NOT NULL in ContactName in the recordset; if it finds it, it will use that name, if not update to say no value recorded.

**EDIT:** After long and hard debugging, turns out to be 0-length string was culprit.  Added [contactname] <> '' to the FindFirst statement to make sure it was looking for those as well.

Comment: Yes - I am just trying this solution.  I do want to let the users know if there is no information for the field - that's what I was trying to do in my snippet above.  So, if your solution works in my context it will be perfect.

Comment: Let me know how it goes.  I just updated again.  I was reading and rereading your post and getting confused - just me at the end of the workday, sorry. :(

Comment: First - thank you for your prompt answer.  I have tried your answer out and, unfortunately, while it runs, it does not populate the textbox in case there is no value found (rs.NoMatch).  Can you think of anything else it may be?

Comment: @SteveCooke:  Yes, see my edit.  I think Me.vcTBConcatName.Text should just be Me.vcTBConcatName.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Thank you again VBlades - I have tried both ways, and I've tried rs.NoMatch = True (as per your earlier edits).  While all run, none populate the textbox in case there is no value to populate with.

Comment: @SteveCooke: Sorry, Steve.  I am running the code (exactly as it is on the answer now) on my own box and it works fine.  Can you put on breakpoint on the code and step through it?  Make sure the conditional is being hit and then step through each line of code to make sure something is not resetting it, please.

Comment: @SteveCooke:  Also, you should remove the Do Until rs.EOF = True, rs.MoveNext, and Loop lines if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Yes - I removed the references to the DO operation.  I will step through as you suggest and get back to you in a few moments

Comment: Wow - I cannot get it to work. I can give more information - maybe that will help.  There is more than one field that I am trying to populate in the same way, from the same result set.  Would this effect the outcome?

Comment: I've also now tried the same code with just one field to populate - same result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56504/discussion-between-vblades-and-steve-cooke).